# Are all <random> distributions thread safe despite not being const?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Notice that std::normal_distribution::operator() is *not* const, nor does it behave in a const way. (Some other distributions have () operators that behave in a const way, but are also not defined to be const).

Given that std::normal_distribution::operator() is not const, is it still safe to use the same normal_distribution object across multiple threads? Is it safe for all distributions in the random header?

**Edit:** That is, the following member function throws an error due to the function being const but using the operator(), which can change d. Is it always safe to fix this by declaring d to be mutable?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass::MyClass(double mu, double sigma)
    {
        d = normal_distribution<double>(mu, sigma);
    }

    double MyClass::foo(std::mt19937_64 & generator) const
    {
        return d(generator);
    }
private:
    std::normal_distribution<double> d;
}
```

Comment: Are `normal_distribution` instances so large that there's a reason to share them across threads at all?

Comment: AFAIK, none of standard methods are thread safe, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @NicolBolas the distribution is fairly lightweight. The random engine is quite large however.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's about code clarity. If the answer is "It's not thread safe" then I need to make a copy of each MyClass object for each thread, or pass the distribution object to the foo function. If the answer is "It is thread safe" then I do not need to make a copy of the MyClass object for each thread, which will be cleaner.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: it really depends from what engine you use. The Mersenne Twister is huge, but any LCG (or any engine of the much better xorshift family) has fairly minimal state.

Comment: @NicolBolas, depends on the algorithm, some algorithms need to use the same instance across threads, some others might not. It is possible/easy to make a copy but it may not be correct from an algorithmic point of view.

Comment: This is *particularly unsafe* for `std::normal_distribution`. All major standard library implementations of that distribution are stateful.

Comment: @T.C. I guess it is stateful because it wants to save some intermediate results to improve the amortized time cost. Is that right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, such objects are not thread safe (as any other standard library object, unless otherwise specified). You shouldn't share any of those objects between threads without protecting them with a mutex or similar construct.

Comment: Fully agree! Usually, these objects are used in a random sampling context. Protecting them with a mutex or critical section can significantly hamper performance. In these cases, I've found it best to let each thread have its own distribution object. Using OpenMP, one can first construct the parallel threads and their objects (#pragma omp parallel) before entering the sampling loop (#pragma omp for). This principle also works for the random number generator.

Comment: Yeah that's what I generally do as well... one rng per thread, seeded in a reproducible fashion from the rng of the thread that starts them.